# can any one help figure this out using python?

Tags: python-3.x

Design a recursive function that accepts two arguments into the parameters x and y. The function should return the value of x times y. Assume that x and y will always be positive nonzero integers. Remember, multiplication can be performed as repeated addition as follows:  8 x 7 = 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8

```
def my(x,y):
    if x==0:
        return 0

    else:

        return x*mul(x,x-1)
assertEqual(my(8,7),56)
assertEqual(my(8,5),40)
assertEqual(my(8,2),16)
```

Comment: I think you should flag this as homework.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code that should do the trick:

```
define mult(x,y):
    if x is zero:
        return zero
    return y plus mult(x-1, y)
```

Now, because I've always thought that Python is an ideal pseudo-code language, that should be fairly easy to convert. The idea with recursion is to define an operation in terms of simpler operations and provide a terminating one.

In order to understand this, imagine what happens when `x` is 3 and `y` is 7.

First time in `mult(3,7)`, `x` is non-zero so the result is `y` (= `7`) plus `mult(2,7)`.

For `mult(2,7)`: result is `y` (= `7`) plus `mult(1,7)`.

For `mult(1,7)`: result is `y` (= `7`) plus `mult(0,7)`.

For `mult(0,7)`: result is zero since `x` is zero.

This gives you `(7 + (7 + (7 + (0))))` or `21`, as expected.